# I want to exclude results that contain a specific element from grouped results, how can I do that in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array
       0: Object
          salesManagerId: ObjectId
       1: Object
          salaesMangerId: Object
  createdAt: Date
},
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array
       0: Object
         salesManagerId: ObjectId
  createdAt: Date
},
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array  //no elements
  createdAt: Date
}
```

The data type is as follows.

What I want is,

```
_id       A      B     C
20211020   30     11    8
20211019   15     14    11
20211018   23      3    0
```

A: It should be output how many _ids are included by date grouped by date.

B: The number of elements in `details` in A. If it has element, count 1. not 0.
If the document is as follows, the value counted after excluding from A becomes B

```
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array  //no elements
  createdAt: Date
}
```

C:
The count of B becomes C, except when there are specific `details.slaesManagerIds` among B. `details.salesManagerIds` is provided as an array. For examples, `[objectId(".."), ObjectId("..")]`

I made query as follows.

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$createdAt"
        }
      },
      A: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      B: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $isArray: "$details"
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      $size: "$details"
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1
    }
  }
])
```

It goes well until B. How can I write a query to get C ?

Comment: I failed to understand the second block where there are table of _ids, a, b, and c. Could you please clarify what are these values?

Comment: thanks @MoaazBhnas. Let's take a first block example.
  
There are a total of 3 documnets, and if 3 documents have `createdAt` equal to `20211020`,`_id` is `20211020`, and 3 should be output for A. If the `createdAt` of one of the three documents is `20211019`, A is 2 when `_id` is `20211020`, and A is 1 when `_id` is `20211019`.

And when `_id` is `20211020` and A is 3, if there are no elements in the three document details, 0 should appear for B. If there is an element in one document, 1 should appear.

Comment: Finally, if B is 1, if details.writerId is included in the array that should be excluded from the document that contains the element in details, C returns 0.

It's a bit difficult to write.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude a document if it has a certain nested field, you can use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

Example:
You have these documents, and you want the ones that don't have `salesManagerId` as a nested field in `details`:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array
       0: Object
         salesManagerId: ObjectId
  createdAt: Date
},
{
  _id: ObjectId
  details: array  //no elements
  createdAt: Date
}
```

This is should be your filter:

```
{"details.salesManagerIds": {$exists: false}
```

This is how I would go about your query above:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$createdAt",
        },
      },
      A: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
      B: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $isArray: "$details",
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      $size: "$details",
                    },
                    0,
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            1,
            0,
          ],
        },
      },
      c: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ "details.salesManagerId": { $exists: false } }, 1, 0],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But what I want is if there are salesMangerId of a, b, c, I want to exclude only the salesManagerId of a. The code you gave seems to be determined by whether the salesManagerId itself exists or not.

Comment: I'm sorry. Help me clarify this.
What is the condition which you want to use to exclude a document? if `details` has `salesManagerId` array or if `salesManagerId` has a specific `writerId`?

Comment: sorry. salesManagerId.

Comment: So,  if `details` has `salesManagerId`, and that what I did in my answer :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735674/how-can-i-exclude-results-that-contain-a-specific-element-from-grouped-results

could you check this question?